# Function that reads last line of file?

Tags: python

The function reads the last line of the file at the specified file path. The function returns the last line of the file as a string, if the file is empty it will return an empty string ("").

I tried writing my code like this but it won't work, it's pretty messy and I'm a beginner

```py
def read_last_line(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        size_file = os.path.getsize(file_path)
        return_file_empty = " "
        last_line = (list(file)[-1])
        print(last_line)
        if size_file == 0:
            return return_file_empty
        else:
            return last_line
```

Comment: Please update your question with the exact reason why it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use:

```
def read_last_line(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        return lines[-1] if lines else ''
```

---

---

for big files you may use:

```
def read_last_line(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        last_line = ''
        for line in f:
            last_line = line
        return last_line
```

Comment: Here `readlines` reads the entire file into a list which you don't want to do if your input is a large file.

Comment: Not all files are databases, but `readlines` is best avoided as it is guaranteed that it reads the entire file contents into a list of string, so you _must_ be able to fit the file in memory. Doing that just to return a single line is inefficient and blocks until the file read is complete and is a waste of memory.

Comment: @Alex now is better my answer ?

Answer (score 3):

This opens the file and moves though it until there is no more file (raises `StopIteration`) and returns the last line.

```py
def read_last_line(filename):
    line = ""
    with open(filename) as fh:
        while True:
            try:
                line = next(fh)
            except StopIteration:
                return line
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to get it like the following. Unlike the currently accepted answer, doesn't require storing the entire file in memory:

```
from collections import deque

def get_last_line(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        try:
            lastline = deque(f, 1)[0]
        except IndexError:  # Empty file.
            lastline = None
        return lastline


print('last line: {}'.format(get_last_line(filename)))
```

Answer (score -1):

If I've understood the question correctly, something like this maybe?

```
def get_last_line(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as file:
        return next(line for line in reversed(file.read().splitlines()) if line)
```

Comment: `file.read()` reads the whole file, you'd be better iterating the file.